# Accurate car fuel consumption with OBD II

Tags: obd-ii

I want to calculate fuel consumption of a car quite accurately with a raspberry pi.
The car I use is a Citroen and has not many available PID for OBD II.
Here are the available PIDs (in decimal) : 1, 3-7, 11-15, 17, 19-21, 18, 31-33, 35, 46, 48, 49, 51, 60, 64, 66, 68, 71, 73, 74, 76-80

So I use a method based on MAF (Mass air flow) estimation described here : http://www.lightner.net/obd2guru/IMAP_AFcalc.

I have ~20% error for the average consumption. But I'm more interested in the immediate consumption, especially during accelerations and decelerations, and this method doesn't work well : when I use the engine brake, I have a >2L/100km consumption instead of 0 (probably because there is an air flow but no fuel flow), and consumption increases with speed at a slower rate than estimated on the dashboard.
I think I need a live estimation of air/fuel ratio.

I would like to find values similar to those displayed on the dashboard, but can't find how to do it. Does the OBC use sensors that are not available via OBD-II ?
2 questions :

- Can I get a better consumption estimation with the data I have on OBD-II ?
- Is there a way to get other data via OBD-II, or via another mean ? (after all the OBC can do it...)

Answer (score 0):

All vehicles are continually trimming fuel rate based on many factors (mostly the #1 O2 sensor) to try to hit 0.5% lean of stoichiometric while operating to meet a power demand.  So you're right, that method is correct in principle, but naiive.

I bet you'd go a long way by towards accuracy by logging the [Commanded Air-Fuel Equivalence Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs) as well.